# Can't play files (music, photos, ...) from Grails web app in Google Chrome but in IE10

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, grails

i recently build a simple Grails web app to browse on my local media files. I run the app on a local machine with a Tomcat server, so all files are located in my network.

To show those files is use f.e. the following html code (recently this is a snipped of the html output from the Grails app):

```
<audio src="Y:\Amazon MP3\Justin Timberlake\The 20_20 Experience (Deluxe Version)\07 - That Girl.mp3" controls autoplay>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

If i use the code in a simple html file, it works in Google Chrome.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Best regards,

Pastho

Comment: what exact problem do you have? where you're storing such files, how you're accessing them, what you get in browser, etc.

Comment: Hey, 

i store the files on a NAS, located on my local network. So the path "Y:\" is the path to my NAS.

If i run the app, my browser only shows the audio player. It can't play the music. In my post you can see the html output, which don't work in Grails, but works in a simple html file.

Comment: Ok i tested the app with the IE10 and there it works... So my problem is now the functionality in Google Chrome.

Comment: @Pastho look in the developer tools for errors.  My guess is you can't load audio from a different domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, it's a security issue. Imagine if third-party html tried to use a local file as the src for anything.

You could try having a Grails controller read the file and then stream it back in a response.

Comment: Yeah that's what i have to do now. The src cannot be a local file for security reasons... In IE10 i used the intranet mode, so everything was fine.